# Can SnakeYAML be used to parse a map of objects?

Tags: java, generics, yaml, classcastexception, snakeyaml

I have the following YAML file:

```
a:
  name: alpha
b:
  name: beta
```

I want to turn this into a `Map<String, Item>`, where an `Item` looks like this:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public static class Item {
    String name;
}
```

My approach was to define a class representing this map:

```
public static class ItemMap extends HashMap<String, Item> {
}
```

And then I parse the file using a `Yaml` object from the `SnakeYAML` library:

```
ItemMap result = new Yaml().loadAs(yaml, ItemMap.class);
```

However, the values in this `ItemMap` are not of type `Item` - they are of type `Map<String, String>` - so when I call `result.get("a")` I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class com.demo.Item
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: It would seem that your attempted way of getting snakeyaml to parse your data into objects didn't work. In raw data terms, you have a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>`, which is what you got back anyhow. You _could_ manually serialize/deserialize these things, but since it looks like you're using a jackson-esque library for this, I would look into some form of type adapter for the library. When I last used snakeyaml (a pretty long time ago), I don't believe there were mechanisms for this, so data types needed a flag for what they were.

Comment: Usually you'd use `putMapPropertyType` but that only works on properties in other beans, not on the root type. You can write a custom constructor but it's quite the hassle.